# backendless not rest api not returning proper response (code:2002)

Tags: php, rest, backendless

Here's what I am trying to do

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$APP_ID= "application-id : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$REST_KEY= "secret-key : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$APP_TYPE= "Content-Type:REST";
$POST = "POST";
$GET ="GET";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $GET);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($APP_ID, $REST_KEY, $APP_TYPE));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.backendless.com/test/data/items";);
$result = curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );
$result = json_decode($result);
echo json_encode($result,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

and in response i am getting this

```
{
"code": 2002,
"message": "Version is disabled or provided wrong application info (application id or secret key)"
}
```

all the keys and ids are correct and the version is also working

what is the problem then???why won't it spit out JSON result correctly??

**updated version**
just remove spaces as shown below

```
$APP_ID= "application-id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$REST_KEY= "secret-key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
```

Comment: I'll just leave a link to the official support forum in case someone runs into the same problem: http://support.backendless.com/topic/cannot-get-proper-response-using-rest-curl-with-php

Comment: where did you get that api URL from? and what is your table name?

Comment: hey guys sorry the space between the colon and header names were creating the error